# app working in local server but not in web container

Tags: android, cordova, sapui5

I wrote an SAPUI5 Mobile application, and it works OK on my local server (it's the app from the tutorial, showing persons list in a table).

I've then put it in a web container via Phonegap (just copied index.html and .js files), and it also runs very nice on an emulator, but it is not adding any persons this time (like there is no function associated to a button).

Should I somehow adapt the code? I've added the needed libraries, too.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide more detail as to what's not working and what you've found in debugging.

Comment: These are the logs:

![Log 1][1]


![Log 2][2]


![Log 3][3]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4qeq8.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qyZzC.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1VTHE.png

Comment: May I be so bold as to suggest you do some work yourself first of all to see where the problem might lie. Don't take this the wrong way, but we're not here to do your debugging for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to the simulator. App is working perfectly on a phone device. Thanks anyway